# Fill points into a pre-rotated convex Dodecahedron

Tags: graphics3d, regions, computational-geometry, polyhedra

I am trying to fill a rotated convex polyhedron with points. This functions well in the unrotated case:

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 2];
inside = Select[pts,Apply@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron","RegionFunction"]];
Graphics3D[{Sphere[inside, 0.1]}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Ticks -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

Now, I would like to do the same but with a previously rotated polyhedron as it can be displayed with:

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[{PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", 
    "GraphicsComplex"]}, RotationMatrix[-36 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

So far, I have tried using `GeometricTransformation` and `Rotate` on `PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron"]`, which didn't work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion), you can transform the region, and then create a [`RegionMemberFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMemberFunction) from it.

```
mesh = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
transform = TransformedRegion[mesh, RotationTransform[-36 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]];
rmf = RegionMember[transform];
```

Then, use `rmf` in your [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select):

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 2];
inside = Select[pts, rmf];
Graphics3D[{Sphere[inside, 0.1]}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Ticks -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

It is also possible to use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) to get random points in the dodecahedron:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[RandomPoint[transform, 10000],.1]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
reg = Dodecahedron[{-36 Degree, 0}];
RegionImage[reg, Quiet @ RegionBounds[reg]]
```

[image]